# Is a sequence in a Hilbert space that forms biorthogonal with a Schauder basis also a Schauder basis?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, wavelets, schauder-basis

Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space and has a Schauder basis $\{e_{j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty} $. $\{\hat{e_{j}}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence biorthogonal with $\{e_{j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$; that is, $<e_{j},\hat{e_{k}}>=\delta_{jk}, $ where $\delta_{jk}=1$ if $j=k$ and otherwise 0.

Is $\{\hat{e_{j}}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ also a Schauder basis? This seems perhaps like a standard exercise but I am having some trouble solving it. I'd be very grateful for any help.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: See [this book](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/karel.pravda-starov/Articles/NonHarmonic.pdf) section 7 'Duality' pages 22-24.